# how can i change orientation by button's click events?

Tags: iphone

I have used TableView and also used Disclosure Button by clicking on  Disclosure Button i have got one Particular Image comes.i want that when i pressed  Disclosure Button i have to get that particular image with performing Orientation so how can i do it.please help me. I am new in this kind of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually transform the table. Here is some code to create and rotate a UITableView around its center.

```
// this defines a constant PORTRAIT_FRAME, which is the frame of the iPhone screen 
// minus the Status Bar. Equivalent to CGRectMake(0,20,320,460). 
#define PORTRAIT_FRAME [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]

// this defines a constant LANDSCAPE_FRAME, for orienting the table sideways
#define LANDSCAPE_FRAME CGRectMake(0,20,480,300)


// this function assumes you have a class variable called myTableView
// and it toggles the orientation of myTableView
- (void) rotateTable {

  if (myTableView.transform == CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)) {
    // rotate the image by 90 degrees  
    myTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2); 
    myTableView.frame = LANDSCAPE_FRAME;
    return;
  }

  // set the image to its original orientation 
  myTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0); 
  myTableView.frame = PORTRAIT_FRAME;

}
```

If you want to trigger this rotation on a button click, then declare a UIButton and assign this function as the action. Here's a function to create a UIButton. Just pass it @"rotateImage" for the action and self for the target.

```
+ (UIButton*) getButtonAtPoint:(CGPoint)point 
                             target:(id)target 
                             action:(NSString*)action {

  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
  [button addTarget:target 
             action:NSSelectorFromString(action)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  return button;
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help but Actually i am using table view and my button is not normal button but it's a Disclosure Button so how can i use this code?

Comment: You can set the transform of a TableView in the exact same way as you set the transform of an imageView... that is myTable.transform = foo. Also, the Disclosure button is just a type of UIButton. I will edit the code above to use that type of button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use UIApplication's setStatusBarOrientation:animated: and rotate/resize your top level view manually. If you use UIView's animation block methods then you should just be able to do this inside an animation block and commit it to get essentially the same effect. Haven't tried this myself though.

Comment: can you show me with example because i have to do this on button click event and i have no idea about this.